# T4 Template relative path

Tags: .net, t4

I have a T4Template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Web" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Web.Mvc" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Web.Mvc" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Web" #>
using System; 
namespace MyNamespace.SomePages
{<#string folderPath = @"D:\_Source\TOG\aaaaaa\bbbbbbb\ccccccc\"; 
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath);
foreach(string folderName in folders){if(!folderName.Contains(".svn")){#>

    public static class <#= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(folderName)#>
    {
<#foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName)){#>
        public const string <#= System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) #> = "<#= System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToString()#>";
<#}#>
    }
<#}}#>}
```

how can i get a relative path for "folderPath" as that path is different on all the developers machines?

Comment: Managed to get an answer:

string folderPath = HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.GetDirectory("~/MyPagesPathj");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.GetDirectory("~/MyPagesPathj");